# Get gallery thumb from inline photo

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a gallery model and a photo model. In my photo model I have a boolean field for selecting which photo should the gallery thumbnail.

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Tittel")

class Photo(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, null=True, blank=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
    frontpage_thumb = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the code Im using now, but that can't be the best way:

```
{% for object in gallery_list %}
    <div class="post">

        {% for thumbnail in object.photo_set.all %}
            {% if thumbnail.frontpage_thumb %}<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ thumbnail.image }}">{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Anyone have a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `Manager` and `QuerySet`, like this:

```
class PhotoQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def frontpage_thumb(self):
        return self.filter(frontpage_thumb=True)

class PhotoManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PhotoQuerySet(self.model)

class Photo(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = PhotoManager()
```

Then you can do things like:

```
# get first thumb for a gallery:
>>> g = Gallery.objects.all()[0]
>>> thumb = g.photo_set.all().frontpage_thumb()[0]

# or all thumbs for all galleries:
>>> all_thumbs = Photo.objects.all().frontpage_thumb()
```

Because your schema doesn't guarantee that you only have one `Photo` per `Gallery` with `frontpage_thumb=True` set, you still have to get the first element of the result in the template, using `.0`, like in the first Python example above:

```
{% for gallery in gallery_list %}
    <img src="{{ gallery.photo_set.all.frontpage_thumb.0.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```